# Chrome renders weird rectangles into "frosted glass" effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I set up a "frosted glass" effect on my login form, but keep getting weird rectangles rendered into it.

This happens only in chrome and only in the desktop variant. Im using chrome 74 on Windows 10.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(10deg, #a1d9b4 20%, #32988a 40%, #000e3c 70%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.loginContainer {
    padding: 15px 14vw 15px 14vw;
    max-width: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.loginContainer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    filter: blur(10px);
    margin: -20px;
}
```

And my JSX:

```
<Container className="container">
    <div className="loginContainer">
        <img src={"/default_light.png"} className="profileImage" alt="" />
        <input className="username" onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" />
        <input className="password" onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <label className="stayLoggedInLabel">Remember me <input className="stayLoggedIn" onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="checkbox" /></label>
        <Link className="forgotPasswordLink" to={"/reset"}>Forgot password?</Link>
        <div className="loginButtonContainer">
            <button className="loginButton" onClick={this.tryLogin}>Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</Container>
```

Result in Chrome:
[Result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km9lW.png)

Result in Firefox:
[Result in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWkI1.png)
Does anynone know how to fix this behaviour?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the full code required to reproduce the issue

Comment: @APAD1 thank you for your fast response! I added the missing code.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just tested your code in Chrome 74.0.3729.157 and I was not able to reproduce the issue you are seeing. It looks just like it does in your Firefox screenshot. Which specific version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: Mh that's weird, I'm using the same chrome version as you and just tested it using another computer with also the same chrome version and this behaviour still occurs.

Comment: Windows or OSX?

Comment: Both machines are running Windows 10

Comment: Ok, I checked it on OSX, so maybe the issue is specific to Windows versions of the browser.